# Exoplayer video plays fullscreen before the complete layout is loaded

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, exoplayer

In my Android application. I have added exoplayer in details activity and it will be reached by clicking a link from the recycler view list item. 
Now the problem is while loading the details screen.

The Exoplayer fills the screen for a moment and then the layout is getting populated. 
I want the video to be loaded into the layout screen after clicking item in list without fullscreen loading. Please find below the gif regarding the same.

[image]

XML layout of the Details screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exo_player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_dark_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exo_player_thumbnail_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/exo_player_progress_bar"
            style="?android:progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />


    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_short_desc_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="short description"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_desc_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="description"
        android:textSize="17dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code using video height and width.
It works fine for videos with 16:9 aspect ratio.

xml:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

java:

```
    ConstraintLayout viewLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout_player);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewLayout.getLayoutParams();
    int videoHeight = 148;
    int videoWidth = 264;
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    params.height = (int) (((float) videoHeight / (float) videoWidth) * (float) screenWidth);
    viewLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the dimension of the SimpleExoPlayerView manually because the player does not know the aspect ratio of your video before loading it, which is asyncronously.

So in onCreate you need to look up the SimpleExoPlayerView with findViewById(int id) and set the height of the LayoutProperies according to the width of the parent view of the SimpleExolayerView and the aspect ratio of the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
//setting the video player height programmatically by screen width
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

    var width = displayMetrics.widthPixels

    val videoHeight = 148
    val videoWidth = 264
    val screenWidth = width
    viewBinding.videoView.layoutParams.height =
        (videoHeight.toFloat() / videoWidth.toFloat() * 
screenWidth.toFloat()).toInt() 
viewBinding.videoView.setLayoutParams(viewBinding.videoView.layoutParams)
```

Just adding this for anyone who may be having the same issue. This is how I implemented Meisam's guidance in my Kotlin project with a viewBinding and it worked perfectly.